# Android - Background Image without margin

Tags: android, image, layout, background

I want to set a image as background in my Activity. 
The problem is that I use margin and the image doesn't fill the whole screen. But I need the margin value.

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:layout_margin="15dp"
 android:background="@drawable/main_background"
 android:orientation="vertical" >
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

replace layout_margin= with padding=, padding is on the inside